# Twenty Seventeen customizer front page section: How to use CPT?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-customizer

Use Twenty Seventeen theme, go to front page, open customizer and click "Theme Options".

We can see Front Page Section 1, 2, 3, & 4

Instead of using Page, how to use custom post type for this section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I solved the same problem.
First you better create a child theme and within it create [CPT](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).
Add new page for displaying CPT and add this page in customizer.

If someone has another simpler solution, please share!